# HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme Anonymous, the authentication header received from the server was OAuth realm

Tags: google-oauth

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'OAuth realm="https://accounts.google.com/OAuthGetRequestToken"'.**

getting the above error while calling the authentication token using google oauth 2.0.
I passed clientid, clientsecret and code returned from user consent.

Below is my request

```
url  : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
body : code=******************
&client_id=********************
&client_secret=****************
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/1565/Link/OnAuthorizeButtonClick
&grant_type=authorization_code
content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell what tech you are using. But have you seen this post?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3651246b-49ae-4f5e-b444-6752bf085910/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous-the-authentication?forum=wcf

Comment: I'm trying to do exchnage the authorization code to access token as per this documnet,  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#exchange-authorization-code